# go mod download won't download a single library; how to mod import a single library without manipulating entire vendor cache

Tags: go, go-modules, prometheus-operator

(disclaimer: apologies for wrong words used in this description. I'm still getting acquainted with go)

My understanding is that `go` modules are pretty finicky so this question kind of spans a few topics related to `go` modules and the `prometheus` operator library I'm trying to download and import.

One huge requirement: I *cannot* do a mass `go mod` download/upgrade as downstream deps get upgraded in my vendor directory and all kinds of havoc happens in our code. I'm trying to avoid that. I just want to "install" this one library (and any necessary ancillaries) and be done with it.

All of that said, what is the proper way to using `go mod` (or another proper tool) to obtain `"github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1"` that will not update all of my vendor libs? I just need to import the `v1` api there to set and read `servicemonitor`s in my clusters programmatically.

```
$ go mod download -x github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1
module github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1: not a known dependency
```

or

```
$ go get github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1
go: found github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1 in github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator v0.41.1
```

my imports

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/intstr"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"

    coreosv1 "github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1"
    "github.com/go-kit/kit/log"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)
```

The actual code I'm using this library for looks like:

```
    // define service monitor object
    serviceMonitorObject := &coreosv1.ServiceMonitor{
        ObjectMeta: metav1.ObjectMeta{
            Name:      objectMetaDataName,
            // TODO: fix namespace
            Namespace: "monitoring",
            Labels:    labels,
        },
        Spec: coreosv1.ServiceMonitorSpec{
            Selector: metav1.LabelSelector{
                MatchLabels: labels,
            },
            NamespaceSelector: coreosv1.NamespaceSelector{
                MatchNames: []string{
                    "monitoring",
                },
            },
            Endpoints: []coreosv1.Endpoint{
                {
                    Port: "metrics",
                    Interval: "10s",
                    HonorLabels: true,
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

However, I cannot seem to just import the one library. Any suggestions or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The error `github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1 in github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator v0.41.1` suggests that maybe I just import `github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator` but when I do that, my `servicemonitor` definition fails.

**EDIT**

I `rm`ed my `go.{mod,sum}` and `vendor` directory and `git reset --hard` my environment, which restored the vendor state to just before my work. I ran the following, but as you can see, the `get` appears to work, but there is no `coreos` directory in existence under `/project/vendor/*/`.

```
$ go get -x github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/coreos/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/@v/list
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/@v/list: 410 Gone (0.794s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/coreos/@v/list: 410 Gone (0.886s)
# get https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/@v/list: 200 OK (0.897s)
go: github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator upgrade => v0.41.1
$ find vendor -name '*prometheus*'
vendor/github.com/go-kit/kit/metrics/prometheus
vendor/github.com/go-kit/kit/metrics/prometheus/prometheus.go
vendor/github.com/prometheus
vendor/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus
```

Reset my environment again. Performed the following:

```
$ go mod download -x github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/...
warning: pattern "github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/..." matched no module dependencies
$ go mod download -x github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/
module github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/: not a known dependency
```

According to documentation, the following should show all mods used (`grep core` added to get more brief output):

```
$ go list -m all | grep core
github.com/coreos/bbolt v1.3.2
github.com/coreos/etcd v3.3.10+incompatible
github.com/coreos/go-etcd v2.0.0+incompatible
github.com/coreos/go-oidc v2.2.1+incompatible
github.com/coreos/go-semver v0.3.0
github.com/coreos/go-systemd v0.0.0-20190321100706-95778dfbb74e
github.com/coreos/pkg v0.0.0-20180928190104-399ea9e2e55f
github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator v0.41.1
```

Yet, I still cannot compile:

```
$ make -f build/Makefile generators ims-bin-darwin && ./ims-api --config_file=/var/tmp/jim-ims-api.yaml --kubeconfig $HOME/.kube/config --populate_demo_db=true --populate_demo_file hack/demo1.yaml --debug_logging --db_debug_logging
./build/generators/api.sh
Ensuring Bin Directory (./build/generators/../../bin) Exists...
Ensuring Destination Directory ( pkg/generated/api ) Exists...
Ensuring Destination Directory ( pkg/generated/kaas-api ) Exists...
Ensuring Swagger Asset Directory ( assets/generated/swagger ) Exists...
go: inconsistent vendoring in /Users/jimconn/projects/src/ims-api:
        github.com/go-kit/kit@v0.10.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates github.com/go-kit/kit@v0.9.0
        github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.4.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.3.2
        github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.14.6: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.9.6
        github.com/pkg/errors@v0.9.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates github.com/pkg/errors@v0.8.1
        github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.6.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.1.0
        golang.org/x/time@v0.0.0-20200416051211-89c76fbcd5d1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates golang.org/x/time@v0.0.0-20190308202827-9d24e82272b4
        google.golang.org/genproto@v0.0.0-20200603110839-e855014d5736: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates google.golang.org/genproto@v0.0.0-20190817000702-55e96fffbd48
        google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates google.golang.org/grpc@v1.23.1
        gopkg.in/yaml.v2@v2.3.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates gopkg.in/yaml.v2@v2.2.8
        k8s.io/api@v0.18.3: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates k8s.io/api@v0.17.2
        k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.18.3: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.17.2
        k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3: is explicitly required in go.mod, but vendor/modules.txt indicates k8s.io/client-go@v0.17.2

run 'go mod vendor' to sync, or use -mod=mod or -mod=readonly to ignore the vendor directory
make: *** [generators] Error 1
```

I ran `go mod vendor` and I'm back in this condition where my entire vendor tree is changed:

```
$ g st
On branch expose-bm-prom
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/expose-bm-prom'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   assets/generated/swagger/api.swagger.json
        modified:   go.mod
        modified:   go.sum
        modified:   pkg/generated/api/api.pb.go
        modified:   pkg/generated/api/api.pb.gw.go
...
        modified:   vendor/sigs.k8s.io/yaml/README.md
        modified:   vendor/sigs.k8s.io/yaml/yaml.go

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        vendor/github.com/cespare/
        vendor/github.com/coreos/
        vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/internal/
        vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb/decode.go
        vendor/github.com/golang/protobuf/jsonpb/encode.go
...
        vendor/k8s.io/client-go/util/workqueue/
        vendor/sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/
        vendor/sigs.k8s.io/yaml/go.mod
        vendor/sigs.k8s.io/yaml/go.sum

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

```
$ g st | grep -c vendor
942    # files changed
```

Is this just the state of the world? Am I not able to import this library without dealing with a huge chunk of changes to the entire vendor tree, which completely breaks my code! This is ridiculous!

Comment: From what I can understand, you should be running `go mod download -x github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator` and then importing `github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1` in your code as currently done.

Comment: I gave it a shot. I appreciate the attempt. Still dealing with the suck. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`go get -d github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1` is the correct way to add a dependency on the latest version of the module that provides that package.

When `go get` adds a module dependency, it upgrades other dependencies as needed in order to satisfy the requirements of the new module. That is probably why you are seeing a lot of changes when you run `go mod vendor`.

If you want to minimize those changes, you may need to explicitly choose an older version (so that it will have older requirements):

```
go get -d github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/pkg/apis/monitoring/v1@$OLD_VERSION
```